# How can I extend/append a list with multiple indexes from a variable?

Tags: python, binary, floating, exponent, mantissa

I am trying to create a binary32 floating point to decimal converter, which is made up of eight bits for the exponent and twenty four bits for the mantissa. I have `exponent = []` and `mantissa = []`. If the user inputs `010000111111101101000000000000000` I want indexes one to eight from `value` to be added to `exponent` and indexes nine to thirty two from `value` to be added onto `mantissa`. I currently have the following spaghetti code to do this:

```
print ("Welcome to August's floating point value to decimal converter!")
value = input("Please enter 32 bit floating value to convert.")
exponent = []
mantissa = []
exponent.append(value[1])
exponent.append(value[2])
exponent.append(value[3])
exponent.append(value[4])
exponent.append(value[5])
exponent.append(value[6])
exponent.append(value[7])
exponent.append(value[8])
print (exponent)
mantissa.append(value[9])
mantissa.append(value[10])
mantissa.append(value[11])
mantissa.append(value[12])
mantissa.append(value[13])
mantissa.append(value[14])
mantissa.append(value[15])
mantissa.append(value[16])
mantissa.append(value[17])
mantissa.append(value[18])
mantissa.append(value[19])
mantissa.append(value[20])
mantissa.append(value[21])
mantissa.append(value[22])
mantissa.append(value[23])
mantissa.append(value[24])
mantissa.append(value[25])
mantissa.append(value[26])
mantissa.append(value[27])
mantissa.append(value[28])
mantissa.append(value[29])
mantissa.append(value[30])
mantissa.append(value[31])
mantissa.append(value[32])
print (mantissa)
```

So rather than appending each index individually I was wondering if there is a way to add them to the list all in one line. I have tried the following `extend` methods:

`exponent.extend(value[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])` and without commas too

`exponent.extend(value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4], value[5], value[6], value[7], value[8], )` which I then realised `extend` only take one argument.

`exponent.extend(value[1-8])` which seem to of subtracted the one and eight.

I tried `exponent = {}` which is a set I believe? And then tried `exponent.update` followed by the multiple indexes with commas. Which then told me it only supports one argument.

Any other suggestions on how to add multiple indexes from `value` to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same code can be written using *string slicing* as:

```
value = input("Please enter 32 bit floating value to convert.")

exponent, mentissa= value[1:9], value[9:]
```

Comment: sir you are too fast for me, I concede my answer and just rather upvote

Comment: Thank you very much for this. However, for the exponent I did `value[1:8]` as the first digit is the sign bit so I didn't want that in the exponent. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AugustWilliams: in that case you have to do `[1:9]` for taking 8 bits as it takes elemnets upto `9-1` i.e 8. check edit

Comment: Ah, yes. Just realised that in the `print`. Thank you!

Comment: @anonymous stop, xD I was merely just poking at the fun of you being faster than me. I hate being slower than someone and I know there's like millions of people faster than me.... T.T I just need to train better (cue rocky theme music or some training music) I will be better!

Answer (score 1):

Although your question was answered with a neat solution I wanted to actually answer your original question. You can add a list to a list by using either of them:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = a + b    # c is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.extend(b)  # a is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Notice that `list.extend` actually modifies the list while the addition itself does not. You can do `a += b` however and achieve the same result as `a.extend(b)`.

So you can do the following:

```
exponent.extend(value[1:9])
```

If you use `list.extend` you can actually use any iterable (like tuple or set) but when you use `a += b` or `c = a + b` they usually both need to be the same type.

Comment: I'm very glad you posted this as it has helped me later on in my program. I need to add a radix to a specific point in the mantissa and I was looking to do this with a list. You have helped me a lot! Thanks!